# what is the difference between uint16_t and unsigned short int incase of 64 bit processor?

Tags: c, linux

I came to use a variable of type `uint16_t`, but am unable to use that data type because of my project limitations. Is it possible to `unsigned short int` instead of `uint16_t`?
I don't know the difference between both of them. Could anybody clarify please?

Comment: have you tried looking for, typedef unsigned short uint16_t?

Comment: @Ishmeet I didn't find any information in case of 64 bit processor

Comment: @Ishmeet I am porting code from one processor to another and i found it

Comment: That the processor is 64 bit is not enough information, the important thing is the ABI that is implemented for your platform. This varies from processor to processor and from OS to OS. And in fact categorizing a processor as 64bit (or not) is an oversimplification that is not very helpful for this kind of questions.

Comment: I once wrote programs for a platform whose compiler didn't provide `uintXX_t`. So I wrote them myself. That helped, although it was not very clean (don't know if I am allowed to according to the C standards).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`uint16_t` is unsigned 16-bit integer.

`unsigned short int` is unsigned short integer, but the size is implementation dependent. The standard only says it's at least 16-bit (i.e, minimum value of `UINT_MAX` is `65535`). In practice, it usually is 16-bit, but you can't take that as guaranteed.

Note:

1. If you want a portable unsigned 16-bit integer, use `uint16_t`.
2. `inttypes.h` and `stdint.h` are both introduced in C99. If you are using C89, define your own type.
3. `uint16_t` may not be provided in certain implementation(See reference below), but `unsigned short int` is always available.

Reference: C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x) §7.20 *Integer types*

> For each type described herein that the implementation provides)  shall declare that typedef name and define the associated macros. Conversely, for each type described herein that the implementation does not provide,  shall not declare that typedef name nor shall it define the associated macros. An implementation shall provide those types described as ‘‘required’’, but need not provide any of the others (described as ‘optional’’).

Comment: In principe, some implementations (and ABI) may have non 16 bit shorts. In practice, all the usual 64 bits processors and ABI (x86-64, Sparc 64, PowerPC 64, Aarch 64) have 16 bits shorts. But `int`-s are usually 32 bits.

Comment: I too have never seen a 64-bit machine that had 32-bit shorts.

Comment: As a side note, consider an implementation where `short int`s are larger than 16 bits and `CHAR_BIT` is 8 (as is almost always the case), then it would simply be *impossible* to define `uint16_t`, AFAICT.

Comment: @Job It is not impossible. The compiler might (as an extension) provide something like `__uint16_t`, and `stdint.h` might contain `typedef __uint16_t uint16_t`.

Comment: @glglgl: You're right, I didn't think about extended integer types.

Answer (score 23):

`uint16_t` is guaranteed to be a unsigned integer that is 16 bits large

`unsigned short int` is guaranteed to be a unsigned `short integer`, where `short integer` is defined by the compiler (and potentially compiler flags) you are currently using. For most compilers for x86 hardware a `short integer` is 16 bits large.

Also note that per [the ANSI C standard](http://www.ericgiguere.com/articles/ansi-c-summary.html) only the minimum size of 16 bits is defined, the maximum size is up to the developer of the compiler

> **Minimum Type Limits**
>
> Any compiler conforming to the Standard must also respect the
>   following limits with respect to the range of values any particular
>   type may accept. Note that these are lower limits: an implementation
>   is free to exceed any or all of these. Note also that the minimum
>   range for a char is dependent on whether or not a char is considered
>   to be signed or unsigned.
>
> **Type    Minimum Range**
>
> ```
> signed char     -127 to +127
> unsigned char      0 to 255
> short int     -32767 to +32767
> unsigned short int 0 to 65535
> ```