Getting the under type using getUnqualifiedDesugaredType() function from CLANG
I have this code in my header file.h:
using UWORD = uint16_t;
UWORD var;

And what I wanted to get is this "uint16_t".
Therefore I wrote this code using CLANG:
std::string qualTypeToUnderTypeStr(const clang::QualType& qualType, const clang::ASTContext& context)
{
    clang::Type const* underType = qualType.getTypePtr()->getUnqualifiedDesugaredType();
    std::string output;
    llvm::raw_string_ostream stream(output);
    clang::PrintingPolicy printingPolicy(context.getLangOpts());
    clang::QualType::print(underType, clang::Qualifiers(), stream, printingPolicy, llvm::Twine());

    return output;
}

which returns "unsigned short" instead of "uint16_t".
Any solutions?

when you alias an alias I don't think there is a way to get the middle name. Whats wrong with getting unsigned short as result? After all, thats the type

This has the smell of an xy problem. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need the string "uint16_t" ?

I would like to have the info about the bit size. Regarding this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693445/what-is-the-difference-between-uint16-t-and-unsigned-short-int-incase-of-64-bit
unsigned short is not always 16bit, so I cannot rely on that data type

the number of bits is sizeof(UWORD) * CHAR_BIT

Yes, but I am parsing a file and all that I have is std::string Output, whish contains string "UWORD". So I cannot use sizeof(UWORD)

std::cout << std::is_same_v<std::uint16_t, unsigned short>; - for many compilers these types are aliases. Still not clear what are you trying to achieve.

Update:
The answer lies in this function in QualType class:
auto baseType = qualType.getSingleStepDesugaredType(context).getTypePtr();

This will return the type before the last "sugar".
